# ArrayStoreException when attempting to store an array of linked list

Tags: java

I'm attempting to create an array of linked list which will deal with hash value collisions. I have an array of an objects which I have tried to store the `linkedList` but it doesn't seem to work. Is there something I'm doing wrong, or is there a more efficient route I should take.

This is the error I get when running my code.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException: linkedList
at p7b.Insert(p7b.java:57)
at p7b.main(p7b.java:31)
```

Here is my method

```
    public static void Insert(int hashVal, String key,int[] arrayNums, Object[] arrayString){


Node newNode = new Node(key,null);
linkedList list = new linkedList();

    if (arrayString[hashVal] == null){

        arrayString[hashVal] = list;
    }
```

Here is the `linkedList` code:

```
    public class linkedList{

private Node head;
private int size;


public linkedList(){
size = 0;
head = null;
}//end default constructor

public boolean isEmpty(){
return size == 0;
}//end isEmpty

public int size(){
return size;
}//end size

protected Node find(int index){
Node curr = head;

for(int skip = 0; skip < index; skip++){
curr = curr.getNext();
}//end for

return curr;

}//end find

public Object get(int index){

if (index >=0 && index < size) {

    // get reference to node, then data in node
    Node curr = find(index);
    Object dataItem = curr.item();
System.out.println(dataItem);
    return dataItem;

}
else
return "error";
}//end get

public void add(int index, String item){

if(index>= 0 && index < size+1){
  if(index == 0) {
  //insert the new node containing item at
  //beginning of list
  Node newNode = new Node(item,head);
  head = newNode;
  head.setNext(head);//--------------------


}

else {
  Node prev = find(index-1);

  //insert the new node containing item after
  //the node that prev references
  Node newNode = new Node(item,head.getNext()); //changed prev to head
  head.setNext(newNode);  //prev.next = newNode --//changed prev to ead
  head = newNode;
}//end if
}
sizeplus();

/*if(index == 16){//fffff
for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
System.out.println(head.item());-------------EXR
head = head.getNext();
System.out.println("----------");
}//ifffffff

}
*/
}//end add

public int sizeplus(){
size+=1;
return size;
}
public void remove(int index){
int num = index;
while(size>0){
//System.out.println("strt");
if(index>= 0 /*&& index < size*/){
  if(index == 0) {
  //delete the first node from the list
  System.out.println("REMOVED :"+head.item());//----------------EXR
  head = head.getNext();
}
else {
    Node prev = find(index-1);

    // delete the node after the node that prev
    //references, save regerence to node
    Node curr = prev.getNext();

    System.out.println(curr.item());
        if(size > 1){

    }
    else{
        System.out.print("is the last one left");
    }
    prev.setNext(curr.getNext());
    curr = prev.getNext();

    index+=num-1;

    }//end if
       size--;
//System.out.println(size+" <-size || index-> " +index);

      }//end if

}

}//end remove

public Node getH(){
  return head;
}

}//end class
```

ALSO: how would i change from linked list to the next
here is  what i tried.

```
    linkedList list = new linkedList(); 
    list = arrayString[i];

p7b.java:44: error: incompatible types
    list = arrayString[i];
                      ^
  required: linkedList
  found:    Object
1 error
```

Comment: Can you show your main method?

Comment: Please name your classes with uppercase letters so there isn't any confusion: this is a common convention.

Comment: You've got an `Object[]` but you're attempting to store instances of `linkedList` in it.  What else do you have in this array?

Comment: @Eran https://www.dropbox.com/s/3o46bp1i3aqanih/p7b.java?dl=0

Comment: @Makoto nothing else is in the array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your main method :

```
Object[] arrayString = new String[40];
...
Insert(hashVal,key,arrayNums,arrayString);
```

You are passing a String array to your method.
Therefore you can't put `linkedList` instances in this array.

If you want this array to contain `linkedList` instances, change the code to :

```
Object[] arrayString = new linkedList[40];
...
Insert(hashVal,key,arrayNums,arrayString);
```

or even better :

```
linkedList[] arrayString = new linkedList[40];
...
Insert(hashVal,key,arrayNums,arrayString);
```

and change the signature of `Insert` to accept a `linkedList[]` instead of `Object[]`.

Comment: ok that fixed it thank you, ok i wanted to traverse and print each linked list why doesn't this code work to change from linked list to the next. this is inside a for loop that traverses the entire array

Comment: linkedList list = new linkedList(); 
 list = arrayString[i];

Comment: @cmehmen is `arrayString` still declared as `Object[]`? If yes, you have to cast that `Object` to `linkedList` : `linkedList list = (linkedList)arrayString[i];`

Answer (score 2):

Here's the culprit:

```
Object[] arrayString = new String[40];
```

You're claiming that it's an `Object[]`, but it's *actually* backed by a `String[]` instead.  Java can't make the determination at compile time that you're not going to be able to store any old `Object` into that array, so it blows up at run time.

What you *should* do is type the array correctly - if it's going to hold `linkedList` entities, it *should* be `linkedList` entities.

```
linkedList[] linkedLists = new linkedList[40];
```

More specifically, you are using the array in a lot of different places.  Be consistent with its usage.

---

Having a few thoughts about your code:  it's not...correct.  You're creating a linked list, right?  There's no reason to use arrays unless the list itself is backed by them.

I can't vouch for the correctness of your `linkedList.add` method right now, but you don't want to use arrays for this at all.  Create a single instance of a linked list *outside* of that method and store all of the data you care about in it.

```
public static void insert(String key, int index, linkedList list) {
    list.add(index, key);
}
```

(As a general thought, linked lists don't have index positions that you simply insert into, so the `index` portion is completely superfluous.)